# Clone transcluding content before any child directives execute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have created a directive for showing an example of another directive in use as part of a [bootstrap-like documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example). Here is an example:

```
<an-example>
  <input ng-model="name" an-spellcheck />
</an-example>
```

I want it to copy the markup that is placed inside of it and put that into a `<code>` tag to show the markup you would need to use the directive.

But `ng-model` adds classes to the input, making it:

```
<input class="ng-scope ng-pristine" ng-model="name" an-spellcheck />
```

Instead, the `example` directive should capture:

```
<input ng-model="name" an-spellcheck />
```

However, I cannot seem to access the transcluded content before any of the inner directives run. Here is [a plunker demonstrating the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEgdat5SDkI22WFMFz3X?p=info).

In the `controller`, `preLink`, and `postLink` functions, the input already has css classes from `ng-model`.

Is there a way to access the content of the `example` directive before angular compiles the child directives?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible because ngTransclude has priority 0 while ngModel has priority 1 (the order of compilation is from higher number to lower). 
Thus the ngModel will always be compiled first. It could be possible to change priority to the  directive in order to make it compile before the ngModel, but the transclude will be applied later

ngModel priority:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

ngTransclude priority:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with priority because that is for [multiple directives on the same element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) and in my case, `ng-transclude` is a parent of `ng-model`